# Engagement plans: Progressing from one state to another is taking significantly longer than the specified timeout

Tags: xdb, session-state, engagement-plans

In short my question is: Why does it usually take significantly longer than the specified timeout time to progress from one state to another in an engagement plan?

**Detailed issue:** A user has been added to an engagement flow and after the session has ended I can verify it in the EA supervisor and in the xDB. I have a simple engagement plan in which the first step has a timeout of 1 minute. I would expect that this timeout is more or less precise but I usually see that it takes somewhere between 10 and 20 minutes to actually progress to the next state. It eventually progresses which I have verified by using a simple action that sends be a basic mail, but it takes a very long time to do so.

**Note:** I am using Sitecore 8.1.3

(This question is a follow up question to [Engagement Plans: Why is a user not added to an engagement plan until the session of a user is timed out?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/engagement-plans-why-is-a-user-not-added-to-an-engagement-plan-until-the-sessio) which is concerned with why users are not added to engagement plans until session ends)

Comment: Have you checked that the processing agent in _Sitecore.EngagementAutomation.TimeoutProcessing.config_ is set up with an `Interval` that is short enough?

Comment: Also, this may happen when the contact gets locked by another session—i.e. if they finished one visit and started another immediately.

Comment: @Dmytro: The interval is set to <Interval>00:00:10</Interval>, but the session lock could be the issue. So if the contact is locked by an active session, he cannot progress from one state to another?

Comment: Exactly. The automation worker will wait until it can get an exclusive lock on the contact before it changes any automation states.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko: I will look into it and get back as soon as possible, but it sounds very reasonable. I think that the timeout values are a bit misleading for an editor/marketeer, because they actually expect it to work . They don't know anything about sessions, locks etc.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko: I have confirmed your explanation. Could you add an answer to the question, so that i can close it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Automation worker running interval

The automation worker is the agent that processes automation state changes with a certain interval.

The first thing you should check is whether the automation worker is executed frequently enough. The default is to run it every 10 seconds, which is a good value for your needs. The setting is located in the configuration file *Sitecore.EngagementAutomation.TimeoutProcessing.config*, under *configuration/sitecore/automationWorker/Interval*:

```xml
<automationWorker type="Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.AutomationWorker, Sitecore.Analytics.Automation" singleInstance="true">
  <ThreadsCount>1</ThreadsCount>
  <Interval>00:00:10</Interval>
  <ContactRepository ref="contactRepository"/>
</automationWorker>
```

Make sure you haven't patched this value to use a longer interval.

## Contact locking

Even though the automation worker runs every 10 seconds, it will only process automation states of unlocked contacts. This may become an issue if a user has a live session on your site—in that case, the corresponding contact's automation states will not be processed until the web session ends.

In your particular case, I suspect that a user's session ended and he started a new session with after a short pause of 1 minute or less. This means that, even though the contact was saved to the Collection database and may have been briefly unlocked, the automation worker didn't have a large enough time window to get an exclusive lock. As a result, the contact's engagement plan actions were executed with more than 20 minutes of delay.

Please also note that the contact will remain locked as long as there is *at least one* live web session of the contact, and then for one extra minute. xDB supports multiple simultaneous contact sessions.

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/session_state/session_state#_Toc396298780

Comment: Thank you for the very elaborate answer. It would be a great idea if Sitecore actually made these limitations very clear in the documentation for the engagement plans.

Comment: @pwind I couldn't agree more.