# Engagement plans for in-session engagement possible?

Tags: engagement-plans

Is it possible to use engagement plans to implement something like,

User visits FAQ page 3 times in one session: Trigger action to show chat panel.

User should be enrolled in engagement plan on first visit of FAQ page.

Are engagement plans intended to be used for such cases, or more for offline stuff, to re-engage people that don't return to your site?

I asked this as I found that SSE questions about engagement plans, not executing during a user's session, explaining here [Engagement Plans: Why is a user not added to an engagement plan until the session of a user is timed out?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/engagement-plans-why-is-a-user-not-added-to-an-engagement-plan-until-the-sessio)