# Triggered Goals not displayed in sitecore analytics tab

Tags: goals

I have created one goal and I set rule as

> trigger when the page name as my item name.

Process that I followed.

1. I have published that goal item.
2. I have added the goal to the page item.
3. I have run the page in published version of the site.
4. Then I noticed sitecore analytics tab did not show the created goals and triggered goals.

Do I missed any steps?

Do I need to enable anonymous contacts ?

Comment: How long did you wait?  it won't show up until the session ends

Comment: 5 mins. Do i need to close the site and reopen the page?

Comment: The session needs to end. It's all explained in detail here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/engagement-plans-why-is-a-user-not-added-to-an-engagement-plan-until-the-sessio

Comment: @MarkCassidy Still i won't show anything. I'm getting the same. Also one more thing, without code how i end up a current session